# Replace minus symbol across whole document

Tags: replace

A program I use has SQL & RTF files to generate reports and I'm wanting to remove all instances of the - (minus) symbol from the resulting document.

I'd tried a SELECT REPLACE but I'm not very good with code and don't know how to select the whole document or if that's possible.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using and what are the documents stored in? Edit your question with the table definition.

Comment: I hope that system is Sarbanes-Oxley compliant!d :-)

Comment: Context: This was for issuing credit notes in an invoicing program that doesn't have that functionality built in. So I invoiced for negative values instead to adjust balances. Credit note documents however should show positive values as credit given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each value that you wish to change from negative to positive with ABS. E.g.

```
SELECT
ABS(value)
```